# Formatting output from Mysql into table & new lines

Tags: php, html, mysql

Essentially I want the output to match and align with the thead. I've tried a few approaches and only created more errors. I am pretty new to coding and I thank all those who've came before and asked questions as the answers have gotten me this far.

Example: http://nightsins.net/nhlrealgm/test/
Enter any active nhl player's last name i.e. Crosby

The output below the tablehead I just can not figure out how to format correctly and join to the table head. The second issue is that say you type in "Cros" and it will return 2 results on the same line. will \n after work? Below is the code I am using minus any markup formatting. Thank you,

```
<table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
<thead>
   <tr>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>POS</th>
        <th>16-17 Fpts</th>
        <th>16-17 Fpts/G</th>
        <th>15-16 Fpts</th>
        <th>15-16 Fpts/G</th>
        <th>14-15 Fpts</th>
        <th>14-15 Fpts/G</th>
        <th>13-14 Fpts</th>
        <th>13-14 Fpts/G</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<?php 
    $i=1;
    while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){
?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $results['Name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['Pos']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPts16']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPG16']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPts15']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPG15']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPts14']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPG14']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPts13']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results['FPG13']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
$i++;
    }
?>
  </tbody>

<?php

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Player not found.";
    }

}
else
{ 
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you completed </thead>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

```
Your just adding <tbody> in ur while loop. remove and close u r table after tbody   

<table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>POS</th>
            <th>16-17 Fpts</th>
            <th>16-17 Fpts/G</th>
            <th>15-16 Fpts</th>
            <th>15-16 Fpts/G</th>
            <th>14-15 Fpts</th>
            <th>14-15 Fpts/G</th>
            <th>13-14 Fpts</th>
            <th>13-14 Fpts/G</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php 
        $i=1;
        while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results))
{
    ?>

        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $results['Name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['Pos']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts16']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG16']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts15']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG15']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts14']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG14']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts13']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG13']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
        }
    ?>
      </tbody>
</table>
    <?php

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Player not found.";
        }

    }
    else
    { 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you, im sure i wont make this simple mistake again by closing the tags prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use the code as follows. You just need to put the tbody outside the while loop.



 <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>POS</th>
            <th>16-17 Fpts</th>
            <th>16-17 Fpts/G</th>
            <th>15-16 Fpts</th>
            <th>15-16 Fpts/G</th>
            <th>14-15 Fpts</th>
            <th>14-15 Fpts/G</th>
            <th>13-14 Fpts</th>
            <th>13-14 Fpts/G</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>    
    <?php 
        $i=1;
        while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){
    ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $results['Name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['Pos']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts16']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG16']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts15']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG15']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts14']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG14']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPts13']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $results['FPG13']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
        }
    ?>
      </tbody>

    <?php

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr><td colspan=10>Player not found.</td></tr>";
        }

    }
    else
    { 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not provided full code as brackets are not ending properly for if statement.. however i m following your code and based on it i found you have ended your `</table>` just after `</thead>` which should not be the case.

Instead you should close after `</tbody>` and you have also not shown us from where your if statement starts .. i hope it has started before `<table>` tag.

So I have come up with below code and hope this makes sense ..

```
<?php

if(2 == 2) // your main if starts which will check your length 
{
    if(1 == 1)
    { // this if statement is to find a player
?>
            <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
            <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th>Player</th>
                    <th>POS</th>
                    <th>16-17 Fpts</th>
                    <th>16-17 Fpts/G</th>
                    <th>15-16 Fpts</th>
                    <th>15-16 Fpts/G</th>
                    <th>14-15 Fpts</th>
                    <th>14-15 Fpts/G</th>
                    <th>13-14 Fpts</th>
                    <th>13-14 Fpts/G</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>


            <?php
                $i=1;
                while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $results['Name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['Pos']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPts16']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPG16']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPts15']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPG15']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPts14']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPG14']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPts13']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $results['FPG13']; ?></td>


                </tr>
            <?php
            $i++;
                }
            ?>
              </tbody>
              </table>
<?php

    } // if statement to find a player ends 
    else
    {
        echo "Player not found.";
    }

} // if statement to find a length ends 
else
{
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```